# Android View to fill center area of Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have this layout:

[image: Activity's layout]

All views fill the entire space horizontally, and they're inside a `LinearLayout` oriented vertically. The blue parts have a fixed height (they have the `wrap_content` property).

The red part is a `ListView`. How can I make it fill that center space if there are not enough elements in the list and at the same time preventing it to push the last two elements down if it has more elements?

So far it doesn't push down the two views under it (with the `layout_weight="1"` property), but if it doesn't have enough elements, it shrinks and makes those two elements go up, leaving an ugly white space under them.

This is what happens:

[image: What i've got]

This is what I expect:

[image: Expected result]

Notice that even though the `ListView` is smaller, the two last views don't go up.

So far I've tried:

- Giving all views a weight (ugly display but sort of works).
- Giving each view a size (different results on different devices).
- Giving the last view the `android:gravity="bottom"` property, but the view still goes up.

**What may work**

I've been messing around and I think a `RelativeLayout` may work, with a property like `layout_alignBottom` that instead of aligning to the end of the given view, it aligned to the start of it.

**SOLUTION**

The solution was to use a `RelativeLayout` and set the list's `layout_above` and `layout_below` properties to that of the elements I want to align it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of options that may work for you. Let me know how it goes.

Option 1: 
Set the containing vertical orientated linear layout to fill_parent / match_parent (they are the same). Then set the gravity or layout gravity of the bottom 2 views to bottom.

Option 2:
Contain the list view in a linear layout with a fixed height. Set the list view to wrap_content.

*EDIT*

You could use relative layouts for this, this link here seems to do what you need
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-fixed-header-and-footer-with-scrollable-content-layout-example.html

Comment: As far as I've tested: Option 1 - the last views seem to ignore the gravity property (I've even cleaned the project and rebuild it but they don't seem to "obey"). Option 2: The buttons leave a space below on a Nexus 5 but they go way out of the screen on a Xperia Tipo (and I don't think it's reasonable to make different layouts for every screen size).

Comment: You can adjust the height of the linearlayout in option 2 programatically. You could set the list view to wrap_content and create an empty view to fill the space using height of 0dp and weight of 1. The downside is if the list is large it will push the views down. Taking that case you could then try to place the list inside a scrollview or framelayout or something but the same problem arises, it needs to have a fixed size.

Comment: see my edited answer for a fixed header/footer with scrollable content example.

Comment: What an idiot, I didn't try the `layout_above` option. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.stackoverflow.app.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: That works, but if the list has less elements (say, only 3) the two TextViews will go up, and that's exactly what I'm trying to fix. Test it.

Comment: See my second screen shot.

Comment: Every parent layout needs android:layout_height="match_parent" to force it to the bottom.

Comment: Here is enough set layout_weight=1 to ListView.

Comment: I don't know what IDE you use but I tried with the exact same code as yours and it didn't work for me. I guess I'll have to stick with the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I test it on emulator and my device.

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping your list view inside the a layout and give the layout the fixed height.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I try to avoid that because some dimensions would not work with certain devices, e.g. 300dp leaves space under the last two buttons on a Nexus 5, but on an Xperia Tipo the views go almost completely outside the screen.